# Variable name with using pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, variable-names

I want to pick from keyboard which array i want to display (i know my code doesn't work i just want to show my problem)

```
 int main(){
            char *a = new char[5];
            char *b = new char[5];
            char name;

            cin >> a;
            cin >> b;
            cin >> name;

            cout << name; 
}
```

Comment: `if (name == 'a') cout << a; else cout << b;`

Comment: i will have char arrays from a-z is there other way to do this with using pointers or something :/

Comment: In the future you may receive better feedback by telling us a bit more of what you have tried and how it failed specifically :)

Comment: Use a `std::map`

Comment: i can't use stl

Comment: @Rooster _"i can't use stl"_ You're already using it.

Comment: @Rooster a better way to say *i can't use stl* is *I can't use library containers*. Otherwise you get response like above, or *No one said anything about STL. We're talking the C++ Standard Library here.* or *Like... Omigawd! STL is, like, soooooo 1990s*

Answer (score 1):

The variable names you use in your code have no meaning once your program is running. You cannot dynamically replace `name` with either `a` or `b`, if thats what you wanted to do.

Making the example simpler (c-style arrays are definitely not for beginners, look at `std::vector` instead), you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int a = 42;
    int b = 102;
    std::cout << "select a or b: ";
    char select;
    std::cin >> select;
    if (select == 'a') std::cout << a;
    else if (select == 'b') std::cout << b;
    else std::cout << "wrong input \n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, if you want to have a number of objects (say, more than 2 or 3) of the same type, you should consider using an array or vector.

So instead of

```
char *a = ...;
char *b = ...;
char *c = ...;
```

Use

```
char *values[] = { ... };
```

Now you can access a value by using an index, i.e. an integer value. For a character a-z, this can easily be done by subtracting the value `'a'` (`'a'-'a'` is 0, `'b'-'a'` is 1, etc).

```
const char *values[] = { "this is a", "this is b" };

char name;
std::cin >> name;
int index = name - 'a';

// TODO: Make sure the index is in range!
const char *value = values[index];
std::cout << value;
```